# How to connect html pages to mysql database?

Tags: mysql, html

I want to know how to connect `html` pages to mysql database? What are the codes?

I also want to know how to add new data to MySQL database when I'm using HTML page and also how to publish the data?

Comment: it is not possible from html. you must use server side scripting language to do that like php or asp or any

Answer (score 31):

HTML are markup languages, basically they are set of tags like `<html>`, `<body>`, which is used to present a website using [css](/questions/tagged/css), and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) as a whole. All these, happen in the clients system or the user you will be browsing the website.

Now, Connecting to a database, happens on whole another level. It happens on **server**, which is where the website is hosted.

So, in order to connect to the database and perform various data related actions, you have to use server-side scripts, like [php](/questions/tagged/php), [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp), [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) etc.

Now, lets see a snippet of connection using MYSQLi Extension of PHP

```
$db = mysqli_connect('hostname','username','password','databasename');
```

This single line code, is enough to get you started, you can mix such code, combined with HTML tags to create a HTML page, which is show data based pages. For example:

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect('hostname','username','password','databasename');
?>
<html>
    <body>
          <?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM `mytable`;";
                $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                      // Display your datas on the page
                }
          ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

In order to insert new data into the database, you can use `phpMyAdmin` or write a `INSERT` query and execute them.

Comment: I wonder if anyone has tried this answer.

Comment: @carloswm85, LOL. Add a warning if you want to.