# Select statement in html

Tags: mysql, sql

This example is using a select statement from MSAccess.
Can I use this example to do a select statement from a table in database (Xammp). Can you suggest me any changes that i have to do. Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "   
   http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
   <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   <!--
  var adOpenDynamic = 2;
   var adLockOptimistic = 3;

  var strDbPath = window.location.pathname";
    var conn_str = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + strDbPath;

   function getAdoDb(strAdoType){
     if (window.ActiveXObject){
    return new ActiveXObject(strAdoType);
   }
    else{
    return ActiveXObject(strAdoType);
    }   
           }

        function showReports(){
              try{
    var strHtml ="";
    strHtml += "<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=1 width=500px 
             align=center>";
    strHtml += "<tr ><td align=center colspan=4><b>Stock List</b></td></tr>";

  //Database Connection
   var conn = getAdoDb("ADODB.Connection");
   conn.open(conn_str, "",   "");

   //Recordset
   var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
   strQuery = "SELECT StockID,StockName,ReOrderLevel,IsActive FROM Stocks";
   rs.open(strQuery, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic);

   if(!rs.bof){          
      rs.MoveFirst();
      while(!rs.eof) {
         strHtml += "<tr>";
         strHtml += " <td width=\"10px\">" + rs.fields(0).value + "</td>";            
         strHtml += " <td width=\"50px\">" + rs.fields(1).value + "</td>";
         strHtml += " <td width=\"10px\">" + rs.fields(2).value + "</td>";                          
         strHtml += " <td width=\"5px\">" + rs.fields(3).value + "</td>";                                      
         strHtml += "</tr>";             

         rs.MoveNext();
      }
     }
     else{
     //No Records.
     strHtml += "<tr colspan=4><td align=center><font color=red>No Records.</font></td>

    </tr>";
    }
    conn.close();   
    strHtml += "</table>"; 
    document.write(strHtml);
    }catch(ex){
   alert(ex.message);
   }
  }         
   </script>
    <title>Stock List</title>
        </head>
         </head>
         <!–<body onload="show_menu()">
           <div id="main" />–>
          <body>
```

This is the script that call the function

```
          <script language="JavaScript">
             showReports();
          </script>
            </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your sql string is very generic and would work on any database platform i can think of.  Getting your connection working however is a complete rewrite.

Comment: can you explain to me how to do the connection

Comment: Well, you're using ADO to talk to Access, you'll want to switch to mysql, which requires a [connector](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/).  Then you might try an answer like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5012335/2589202)