# Heroku wont work with my Keyv and Sqlite database

Tags: node.js, database, sqlite, discord.js

Ive made a database from sqlite and i uploaded that with my github to Heroku but its only getting the data from the database and not changing it. No errors, just not working. When i am testing it on my pc it works fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Database on a personal github page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31655085/database-on-a-personal-github-page)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're only able to get data and not change it. If you can share an example of how you're getting and setting, I might be able to help you get it going temporarily.

I learned, however, that [SQLite only offers temporary storage on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3):

> ### Why is SQLite a bad fit for running on Heroku?
>
> #### Disk backed storage
>
> SQLite runs in memory, and backs up its data store in files on disk. While this strategy works well for development, Heroku’s Cedar stack has an ephemeral filesystem. You can write to it, and you can read from it, but the contents will be cleared periodically. If you were to use SQLite on Heroku, you would lose your entire database at least once every 24 hours.
>
> Even if Heroku’s disks were persistent running SQLite would still not be a good fit. Since SQLite does not run as a service, each dyno would run a separate running copy. Each of these copies need their own disk backed store. This would mean that each dyno powering your app would have a different set of data since the disks are not synchronized.
>
> Instead of using SQLite on Heroku you can configure your app to run on Postgres.

I then followed [their instructions for setting up Postgre](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql). It's worth reading through the instructions, but the gist of it to use the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli):

*From the section [Provisioning Heroku Postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres):*

1. "Use the `heroku addons` command to determine whether your app already has Heroku Postgres provisioned"
2. If `heroku-postgresql` doesn’t appear in your app’s list of add-ons, you can provision it with the following CLI command: `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev`

   - As of writing, the hobby tier is free. [Read about plans here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans).
3. This command adds an environment variable to your project named `DATABASE_URL`.

I'm using [**`keyv`** by Luke Childs](https://github.com/lukechilds/keyv). I installed its companion **[`@keyv/postgres`](https://github.com/lukechilds/keyv-postgres)**. (I also uninstalled my `sqlite` stuff.)

I used the newly added `DATABASE_URL` environment variable to wire into the `keyv` steps linked above:

```js
const Keyv = require('keyv');
const keyv =
  process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"
    ? new Keyv()
    : new Keyv(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
```

I haven't found the best solution yet for developing/testing Postgre locally. [Heroku Postgre requires SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#heroku-postgres-ssl) for connecting remotely (when your app is running locally). In the code block above, you'll see that I'm initializing Keyv without a database while developing locally (`new Keyv()`).

From here, if I need to verify the DB storage, I can set up a PostgreDB for developing locally, but I also imagine that it's possible to connect to the Heroku Postgre using SSL. If you or anyone has a solution they like for this step, please let me know.

@T. Rotzooi, I'm three months late to your question, but perhaps this explanation could help future people. I haven't found any other resources discussing this issue that you and I both encountered.