# Can i run a lamp stack on GitHub

Tags: mysql, github, model-view-controller, lamp

My model is as much a part of my app as the view and controller code, so github should support it. Ideally it would treat changes to the data in the database as well as changes to the schema just like a normal commit.

Comment: Are you asking whether this is supported on GitHub Pages?  Or are you asking if you can use your repository as a database?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31655085/database-on-a-personal-github-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub does not run apps.

It doesn't give you a database.