# can i connect my html with database without using php,is it possible?

Tags: php, html, database, wamp

```html
<html>
 <head>
      <title> Futja e te dhenave nepermjet nje forme </title>
            <style type = "text/css">
         body  { background-color: #cfd0f9 }
         h2    { font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                 color: blue }
        h3     {font-color: yellow}

          .error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
   </head>
<body>

<h1><center>please enter data</center></h1>

<p> <span class="error">* please fill these fields.</span> </p>
<form method="post" action="insert.php">

  <strong> Emri:&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </strong> <input type="text" name="fname" />
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $fnameErr;?></span>
   <br>

   <strong> Mbiemri:&nbsp &nbsp </strong> <input type="text" name="lname" />
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $dtlErr;?></span>
   <br>


<input type="submit" name= "shto" value="Add"/>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

our class teacher gives a project about how to connect a html page withe database.

But i am searching tutorial evrywhere but where ever i see there they are connecting html with the help of php?
so, can i connect html page without using php in database? How?

Comment: HTML is specially markup language, usimg html you can present you website via css, and javascript. You can not connect to mysql using HTML.

Comment: no you cannot. you need a back end tool like php

Comment: html is a front end tool (everything is performed on a client side), if you can connect to a database on a client side, your database becomes vulnerable af. That is why you need a back end tool like php to connect to db on a server side

Comment: You may find your full answer by read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012335/how-to-connect-html-pages-to-mysql-database

Comment: You may find your full answer by read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012335/how-to-connect-html-pages-to-mysql-database

Comment: Tnx anyway i got my answer

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you cannot connect to database without having a backend environment setup. XAMPP is a widely known package that gives you PHP, MySQL, and Apache Web Server to let you create web pages using a relational database. With 1 install, it gives you everything you need for a full-stack website. Once installed, there is a directory called `htdocs` where you can create a folder for your project and test your code in a local web server.

Please understand that HTML and CSS are nothing but languages to create the webpage UI. If you want dynamic web pages that require processing data, you would have to bring JavaScript for client-side computation and PHP/MySQL for database access.

[XAMPP Website](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, using **PHP** is one way to connect databases to our html file and to access mysql functions inside the editor. Because when using localhost/phpmyadmin the extension file that we are using is .php